# Objects fly away without animation

Tags: animation, objects, transforms

Novice here. When I slide my cube around my bowling pins, they explode away as soon as the animation starts. To my knowledge, I have not added any animation keyframes to cause this. The pins don't fly away when the box is slid away from them. Im curious what is causing this unanimated movement. Ill include the blend file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, the file has no obvious problems, can you clarify please? It is a [simple bowling ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a614e.gif) knocking down pins.

Comment: Here is a Gif of the issue i'm having. The pins explode away as soon as the playhead starts. https://imgur.com/a/T1LZUZ8

Comment: Possibly your rigid bodies have baked physics which need to be reset, simply moving one somewhere then putting it back will clear it.

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded your file and it animates smoothly.

Please try deleting your cache -> Deleting all bakes

[image]

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for looking into it. Unfortunately I gave it a shot to no avail... I'll keep digging.