# Object animated early, before rigid body collision occurs

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I am practicing my blender-fu by doing a (supposedly) simple animation of a bowling ball hitting some bowling pins. I have set up my objects. I have checked the settings and all the pins appear to have the same settings.

I have not baked anything yet. But I did try "Cache - Delete all bakes' as suggested in https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/208086/49849.

When I start the animation, the head pin starts to fly back as if it had been hit by something. Interestingly, the other pins behave as expected.

My current workspace, set on frame 2:

[image]

[image]

What is happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your pins have holes at the bottom, I think you should not use mesh shape, it may cause some intersections in physics, which tells blender to throw pin away. Change it to Convex Hull, and remove collision.

[image]

After that, I noted that pin doesn't  throw  away, but gently falls down.
I found that it is because it sits directly over the edge, so I moved it a little bit, and the problem was gone. Not sure about what, maybe it is a bug.

[image]

Comment: Moving the line back half a foot did solve the problem. I had not intended to use the mesh and it was showing up as convex when I did my side by side comparison so there may have been a slight bug in the data too.

Answer (score 1):

Your lead pin does *not* have the same settings.  It does not have rigid body physics; it has collision only (which doesn't interact with rigid body physics, by the way.)  It has, in some way, acquired a cache that makes it move.  Apparently, a few other pins have as well (pins with RB rather than collision.)  Something is bugged, but it's hard to say what from your file.

The easiest way to fix that pin is to delete it and then duplicate an existing pin and move it into place.

If you have any, you will probably have to delete your rigid body bake.  It's not necessary to rebake again until you render.  Deleting the lead pin appears to delete the hidden cache for any other objects acting according to that cache.

Comment: Funny, not sure how I missed the collision modifier. And the 'mesh setting' because I did direct comparisons - unless something did go buggy with the file at that point in time.